# Interpretation of $k^{th}$ moment of a random variable ( Moment-generating Functions )

Tags: statistics, moment-generating-functions

Hello I am a math major doing a stats minor currently in undergrad. I am understanding the motivation and derivation of moment-generating functions but I am having trouble understanding what a moment means when the $k>2$.

If I am correct I believe moments are just statistical parameters like, mean, variance, and so forth. (Correct me if I am wrong!)

with $k=1$  we get $E(X)$ and with $k=2$ we get $E(X^2)$ which is not necessarily variance but we can easily find it if we have $E(X)$ since $Var(X) = E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$.

But now I am having trouble understanding what the moments of $k>2$ imply or how can we use them to find such parameters. Your help and expertise would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you heard of [skewness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Pearson's_moment_coefficient_of_skewness) and [kurtosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis)?

Comment: I removed that post, my apologies.